# How to give a user write permissions to a file whereas the group he is in is denied to write (in Active Directory)?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, active-directory

For example, I have a group **Department A**. Among other users, I have a user named **Boss**.
I want to create a file that can be changed only by **Boss**, and be readonly for the other users from that group.

I know that deny on the group level overrides allow on the user level so I can't do what I need just with share/ntfs permissions.

Here I see two solutions:

1. Create a subgroup, for example, **Department A without boss**, deny that subgroup to write, and grant **Department A** permission to write. Will that work?
2. Homer Simpson's approach. Set permissions individually for each user from a group.

Is there any elegant solution to this?

PS: OS is **Windows 2003 Server**

Comment: You should specify your OS to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use deny. Instead:

- Allow read for group "Department A"
- Allow read+write for user "Boss"

Comment: Thanks, that works. Meanwhile I did the Homer's way with powershell scripting by iterating through all users in "Department A" %)